# The reason for the error connecting to the server GlassFish in project Intelij?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-8, glassfish-5

```
[2019-10-12T11:06:32.875+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1570867592875] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [web_war_exploded]]]

[2019-10-12T11:06:32.876+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1570867592876] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/home/vladimir/Downloads/glassfish-5.0/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 27; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web_war_exploded].  TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee'.
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:828)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:610)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2447)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
    ... 51 more
]]

[2019-10-12T11:06:32.903+0300] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1570867592903] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [web_war_exploded] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/home/vladimir/Downloads/glassfish-5.0/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 27; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web_war_exploded].  TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee'.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/home/vladimir/Downloads/glassfish-5.0/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 27; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web_war_exploded].  TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee'.
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:679)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4137)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandler.java:828)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:610)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2447)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1768)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
    ... 51 more
]]
```

Comment: provide more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long error message preceding the stack trace (reformatted for clarity) explains the problem:

```
java.io.IOException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException
publicId: 
file:/home/vladimir/Downloads/glassfish-5.0/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/schemas/web-app_4_0.xsd;
lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 27; 
Deployment descriptor file  in archive [web_war_exploded].  
TargetNamespace.1: 
Expecting namespace
'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'
, but the target namespace of the schema document is 
'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee'.
```

So there is a mismatch between the namespace specified in Glassfish's schema definition (**web-app_4_0.xsd**) and the one you provided in your deployment descriptor (**WEB-INF/web.xml**) for your application.

This is the top level content of Glassfish's **web-app_4_0.xsd**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:javaee="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            version="4.0">
...

</xsd:schema>
```

Note that the value specified for **`targetNamespace`** and **`xmlns:javaee`** is `"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"` so that is the value you should be specifying in your application's **web.xml** instead of `"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"`. To fix:

- Stop Glassfish
- In your application's **web.xml** replace all occurrences of **`http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee`** with **`http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee`**.
- Clean, build and redeploy your application.
- Restart your Glassfish server.

I'm guessing that your problem has arisen because you have an existing application that you are migrating to use EE 8. Oracle has a useful article on schema definitions for the different EE versions titled [Java EE: XML Schemas for Java EE Deployment Descriptors](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html#8), and it points out that for EE 8:

> All new schemas are in the **http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/**
>   namespace. Most older schemas remain in the
>   **http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/** namespace.